# How can I write two dictionaries to be equal but not identical?

Tags: python

I want two dictionaries to be equal but not identical, so that I can modify one without changing the other.
Here's an example on Python:

`a={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}`

`b={key:a[key] for key in a}`

`b['b'][0]=5`

Everytime I do that I'm changing both b and a! How can I *not* do that?

Comment: `b={key:list(a[key]) for key in a}`

Comment: They aren't identical, but the *lists inside of them are*. So just do something like `{k:v.copy() for k,v in a.items()}`

Answer (score 2):

In `b`, when you say `a[key]`, the value of that key is pointing to the same list which the value of relevant `key` in dictionary `a` points to. Instead you can do a deep copy. It takes care of any level of nesting for containers.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

a = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
b = deepcopy(a)

b['b'][0] = 5
print(a)
```

output:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dictionaries store a reference to the list for each key here (because lists are mutable). If you copy the lists, the problem goes away

```
a={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}
b={key:a[key].copy() for key in a}
b['b'][0]=5
```